# Prove: If the five points of a conic are rational, then it contains infinitely many rational points.

Tags: conic-sections

Sketch a proof: If the five points of a conic are rational, then it contains infinitely many rational points.

In class, we learned about Pascal's Theorem for a hexagon inscribed in a conic. The hexagon may be inscribed in a conic iff the three intersections of opposite sides are co-linear.

And I know that there are either no rational points or infinitely many rational points on a rational conic and also that the intersection of two rational lines is rational ... but I am unsure if I can use those in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Consider irreducible conics defined over $\mathbb Q$, i.e. curves of degree two with rational coefficients. Such an irreducible conic in the projective plane over $\mathbb Q$, the field of algebraic numbers, is defined by an irreducible homo- geneous polynomial $G \in \mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ of degree two as the set {$(\bar x : \bar y : \bar z) ∈ \mathbb P^2(\mathbb Q) | G(\bar x, \bar y, \bar z) = 0$}. In the sequel we refer to $$G(x,y,z)=ax^2 +bxy+cy^2 +dxz+eyz+fz^2 =0,...(1)$$ or $$g(x,y)=G(x,y,1)=ax^2 +bxy+cy^2 +dx+ey+f =0,...(2)$$
as the General Conic Equation. $(1)$ defines the projective and the corresponding affine conic, respectively. We denote the projective conic by $C^*$ and the affine conic by $C$.
**Definition**: We call $P = (\bar x :\bar  y : \bar z) \in C^*$ a rational point on $C^*$ iff $P \in \mathbb P^2(\mathbb Q)$. Analogously for the corresponding affine curve.

> **Theorem**: An irreducible conic defined over $\mathbb Q$ has no or infinitely many rational points.
>
> > **Proof**: We give only a sketch of the proof. Suppose there is a rational point P on the conic. Then we intersect the conic with a line through this rational point having a rational direction vector. We will usually get two intersection points – the original rational point P and an additional rational point. Varying the slope of the line leads to infinitely many other rational points on the conic.
> >     Hence, the theorem shows that the existence of one rational point on an irreducible conic implies that there are infinitely many rational points on it.

Comment: The OP seems to know this theorem. remains to show that every conic with 5 rational points is defined over $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Given five rational points $A,B,C,D,E$, we can find a sixth rational point as follows:

1. Let $G$ be the intersction of $AB$ and $DE$.
2. Let $H$ be a rational point on $CD$.
3. The line $AH$ intersects the conic in another point $F$
4. Let $K$ be the intersection of $GH$ and $EF$.

Now $G=AB\cap DE$, $H=CD\cap FA$, $K=EF\cap BC$ are on the Pascal line of the hexagon $ABCDEF$. 
As $A,B,D,E$ are rational, so is $G=AB\cap DE$.
As $A,G,B,C$ are rational, $K=AG\cap BC$ is rational.
As $A,H,E,K$ are rational, $F=AH\cap EK$ is rational.
So in order to show that there are infinitely many rational points $F$, it suffices to show that the above construction is possible in infinitely many ways.

Step 1 is clear. Step 2 is possible in infinitely many ways because $CD$ is a rational line and contains infinitely many rational points.
For step 3, first note that $A$ is not on $BC$, hence the infinitely many lines $AH$ for different choices of $H$ are pairwise different.Also, there are at most two lines through $A$ that do not intersect the conic again. Hence step 3 still works for infinitely many $H$. Step 4 is "deterministic" again; note that in case of parallel lines, $K=\infty$ is still counted as rational.